# Is it possible for 'show' action not to go through database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash

For example, In order to see user related information, we can write this:

controller

```
def show
@user = User.find(params[:id]) # localhost:3000/users/1
end
```

view

```
User is <%= @user.age %> yr old # User is 18 yr old
```

In the case that we don't put the information in database, instead we just parse them from a xml feed and get format like this for example:

```
{ "Alex" => {:age => 18, :location => "Australia"}, "Peter" => {:age => 20, :location => "Canada"}}
```

controller

```
def show
@user = ???? # localhost:3000/users/alex
end
```

view

```
@user is <%= @user.age %> yr old # Alex is 18 yr old
```

What can I write to replace "????" in the controller, so that I can go to localhost:3000/users/alex and see "Alex is 18 yr old", with the code written in view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you're best looking up [user stories](https://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/agile/user-stories) - it will give you a much clearer way of describing your needs.

---

> so that I can go to `localhost:3000/users/alex`

[`friendly_id`](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)

Install the gem, add the following to your `User` model, and you'll be able to look up via a *slug*:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   extend FriendlyID
   friendly_id :name
end
```

This will then allow you to use the following:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @user = User.find params[:id] #-> you can send :id as either the id or name
   end
end
```

To get this working, you *will* need to add a `slug` column to your `users` table:

```
$ rails g migration AddSlugtoUsers

#db/migrate/add_slug_to_users______.rb
class AddSlugtoUsers
    def change
       add_column :users, :slug, :string
    end
end
```

---

> What can I write to replace `????` in the controller,

You can write anything you want.

There are no *rules* with Rails, only guidelines. Rails is a framework and although prefers [convention over configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration), you're still at liberty to do as you need with it.

When you ask...

> instead we just parse them from a xml feed

You're actually wrong. You're parsing them *from* a *variable*.

The XML notation is just a [Ruby Hash](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html) - built as an *object* which can be manipulated in the view.

To understand how this works, you need to read up on the [MVC programming pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), with which Rails is based:

[image]

This shows how the *view* inherits data from the *controller*, which pulls its data from the database. You question about how you can make a *view* pull information from the db, the answer is that it doesn't... the controller does.

Rails controllers set *instance variables*, which you can call in your views to populate them. The XML format is just the way in which the data is passed between them.

As such, when you realize that all your "data building" occurs in the controller, and that your view is simply a conduit for it, you'll be able to use your controller to build the data you need.

Comment: Excellent answer. Also I would question the use of XML in the first place - OK if you have to fetch the data on a per request basis if you were doing something like a stock ticker. But if you just want to skirt using a RBDMS because of simplicity/ [reasons] than a better solution is to use  Memcached / Redis or some kind of key / value store. Parsing and searching XML documents uses a lot of memory and is slow.

Comment: Nice comment, thanks. The way I read the question was the OP wanted to make their data constructs much simpler, so they could access `url.com/users/alex`, and wanted to use XML notation to do it. But you are correct in that pulling from third party services just adds latency and processing time which is not necessary

Comment: Thanks. I am pulling xml feeds from third party, parse them into hash in controller, and display them directly in views. So do you think it is better if I download xml feeds, store them in redis and pull them from redis to display on the page? The feeds are updating every 30 minutes.

Comment: Sure, but why are you downloading your users from a third party? Why not use oAuth or something?

Comment: Actually users are just an example, I am downloading files such as this http://tipgin.net/examples/soccer_odds.xml, map them into hash, and display in views as table data. Just wondering my method is correct, or should I save them into db first? Thanks for your advice!